# Before filter, calling a method with param throws syntax error. Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, before-filter

im trying to understand why this throws error

```
before_filter :check_user_validity(params[:user_id])
```

error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end before_filter :check_user_validity(params[:user_id])
```

but this not:

```
before_filter -> { check_user_validity(params[:user_id]) }
```

why we need to use proc or lambda in before filter, for calling methods with params.

for calling methods without params, it doesn't throws error.

can anyone give the particular reason for the why it throws error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:check_user_validity` is a symbol which is something like a string. You can't "run" a symbol with parentheses. You are effectively doing something like `'function_name'(...)` which is invalid syntax.

`before_filter` or `before_action` works by passing it a function name (by using symbols) or function (by using proc/lambda) to be called later when a request is received.

Answer (score 2):

It's because Rails framework was designed like that.

You're not calling a method `check_user_validity` itself, but rather calling an special `ApplicationController` class method `before_filter`, passing a parameter with a symbol that is a method name you want to call before some actions. In your case it's `:check_user_validity`.

You can also pass a lambda to `before_filter` if you want your method to be called with some arguments.

Also, there is no need to pass `params[:user_id]` to this method as all controller instance methods have access to `params`. So you can just go like this:

```
def check_user_validity
  user_id = params[:user_id]

  ...
end
```